# How to generate 14 digit long random number in postman using lodash?

Tags: postman, lodash

How to generate a fix length 14 digit long random number. I am using postman and lodash lib but somehow sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't

```
pm.globals.set('randomNumer_SO',_.random(1, 100000000000000));
```

This sometimes generate 13 digit number too. But I always want a 14 digit as else API fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `_.random(1, 100000000000000)` you ask for a number between 1 (length 1), and 100000000000000 (length 15). Most of the time, you'll get numbers with length 14, but you might also get numbers of length 1, 2, 3, etc...

To get a number with fixed length of 14, set the lower and upper bounds to the minimal and maximal numbers with that length:

```
_.random(10000000000000, 99999999999999)
```

Comment: Had trouble figuring out how to apply this, so adding how I did it and the observed result:

In pre-request scripts: 
`pm.environment.set("userZipcode",_.random(00000, 99999));`
In request body:
`"zip": {{userZipcode}}`
Which generated a 5-digit number between 00000 and 99999. Cheers (and thanks for the solve!)